# Управление джойстиком

Tags: unity3d

Как обратиться к джойстикам?

```
 float h = Input.GetAxis("Vert_J");
 float xPos = h * range;
```

конкретнее - inputManager
[image: 123]

Comment: @0xdb А зачем картинку-то оставили? Она здесь вообще не в тему.

Comment: @VerNick, вставил я. потому что не понимаю как обращаться к такому джойстику. ведь у него 2 управляемых джойстика и обращаться нужно к обоим

Comment: Люди и так поймут.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.html

Comment: @VerNick Из за комментария "У нас не бывает левых картинок". Что в ней не так? Если ТС считает, что нужна, почему нет.

Comment: @0xdb Я думаю, что она вообще не в тему. Автор сказал джойстик, значит 
 джойстик, и картинок не надо.

Comment: @VerNick Есть джойстики с одним стиком.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Нормальные ответы учтут все варианты.

Comment: @VerNick Но "нормальный" ответ дадите, конечно же, не вы? :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Ну я поискал, но решений с таким джойстиком не нашел.

Comment: @VerNick, раз вы не разбираетесь - не утверждайте, что "нормальный" ответ будет что-то там учитывать.

Comment: @VerNick, я прекрасно знаю про эту ссылку. проблема в том, что там джойстик и рычаг. я не знаю как мне обращаться отдельно к джойстику и отдельно к рычагу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

привязывать кнопку нужно тут